# How to build React Native iOS app, get an .app file and deploy to device?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm going by this information:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content

I did the `react-native bundle` command, changed `AppDelegate.m`, and I can build with success. Though I'm not sure where it's putting the final build. Where is it putting the .app file, and when I want to copy that .app file to my phone, should I sync it via iTunes, or is there a quicker way?

Basically I'm just trying to create and deploy a standalone app that doesn't need the React packager server.

Comment: were you able to achieve a standalone app?

Comment: the link you posted is no longer valid.

Answer (score 36):

I don't know if it is possible to sideload a built app into a phone via iTunes - but if it is possible, the steps to to achieve it would be the same as if you were to deploy a regular iOS app in the same way.

Typically you would deploy a standalone app to a device using TestFlight, via the regular app store submission process:

1. Log into [Apple Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) with the Apple ID tied to your developer account (or register for a new developer account)
2. Generate provisioning profiles for Ad-Hoc deployment and App Store deployment
3. Download and install the provisioning profiles by double clicking them in OSX finder.
4. Package javascript bundle with `react-native bundle`
5. In Xcode project properties select your App Store distribution profile under the `Build Settings` tab. Bump Version and Build numbers under the `General` tab.
6. In the top of the screen, select your production build scheme, and `Generic iOS Device` (or any plugged in iDevice) as build target.
7. Run `Product > Archive`
8. Open `Window > Organizer`, choose your build and press `Upload to App Store...`
9. Log in to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) with your developer account, and under `TestFlight` tab click `Select Version to Test` (it might take a while for your new build be be available for testing).
10. Wait for Apple to approve your app for testing (Internal Testing apps should be quick, External Testing apps need to go through a lightweight approval process).
11. Once app is approved for TestFlight testing, copy the link to your test app and follow the given instructions.

If this seems like a lot of hassle - it is. But going through this process is worth it, as it is the prerequisite to be able to submit the app for download in the App Store, and the sooner get this process in place, the easier it will be to release the app to the public.

Comment: Attention to step 6, where you need to go to `Project -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme (cmd + <)`, make sure you're in the `Run` tab from the side, and set the Build Configuration dropdown to `release`.
Info taken from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content)

Comment: Is it still valid as of 11/2017? I see no mention of react-native-bundle anymore but there's a `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`

Comment: @this.lau_ I had a typo in there, edited it. The command it `react-native bundle`, not `react-native-bundle`. You'll need to provide a few parameters in it, but the CLI will tell you what you're missing. Beyond that, the same bundling command is still valid - `react-native run-ios` will run and deploy the app, but it won't get you the .ipa.

Comment: @jevakalio Would you explaining why I need to make the bundle?

Comment: @Norfeldt - you don't.  There is a custom shell script registered in the xcode build process that does it for you.  Instructions that say you need to do this are out-of-date.