# How to build reactnative v0.45 project to ios realse

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using the latest reactnative verion 0.45 and I didn't get a clue on the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production) about how to build the ios release.

About how to the running on ios device section of the doc quoted here:

> Connect your iOS device to your Mac using a USB to Lightning cable.
>   Navigate to the ios folder in your project, then open the .xcodeproj
>   file within it using Xcode.

But there is no `ios` folder found after running command `npm ios`. And most StackOverflow answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982804/2288944) require a command like `react-native-bundle` which was not found either.

I have already got Xcode and an app develop member account and Really want to build my first reactnative app to my iphone before I could do more stuff on it.

I know this might be a very newbie question. If someone could just give some guide or throw some docs about this?

Answer (score 3):

I stuck on this problem since a few days too, unless you will not get an `ios` or `android` folder any more with React Native 0.45.

You can build your standalone app by using Expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html

As I understand, they build your app for you online, so it takes some time and require an free expo-account, but after it finised, you can download your `.apk` or `.ipa` to submit it to Play Store or AppStore.

When you want to add more custom (non javascript) code to your project and edit it in Andoid Studio or Xcode, so you have to eject your from Reative Native: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

After that, you can test your App by building for your own in the simulator, with no need of the Expo-App.

Comment: thanks，will follow your advice and see what it come out：D

Comment: Hi, BNY, I am following your instructor try to figure this out, but I couldn't find the `exp.json` under the folder after login in with `exp login` [as this doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html#2-configure-expjson) specifies, Do you have any advice to share? Does that will be created automatically or should I create that file manually? Thanks!

Comment: finally, I am in the progress of building my app now, It's feeling waired that I have to give my apple id and password to expo though... even it's an open source project. And it seems the `exp.json` should be once called `app.json`, so just rename that `app.json` to `exp.json` and add stuff required.

Comment: After some practice I decided switching to building a new project with native code and rejected all the Expo stuff. Its pretty easy: just start a new Project with the CLI tool of React Native by: `react-native init AwesomeProject` and copy all your `js` files into your new project. So you have all your files like exepted (`ios/android`). I was totally wrong, that you will not getting these folders with RN45, I just startet my project wrong...

Answer (score 0):

- Open the `ios` folder of your project using xcode
  [image: Select ios folder]
- Connect your phone and select your phone from the device selection dropdown[image: Choose your iPhone]
- Select the first tab in the explorer and go to `signing` area, select your development team
  [image: Select first tab]
  [image: Select team]
- Click play and it will install the app in your phone on development mode

For Production build, you can do the same. However, you would need to change your scheme to production:

- Open `scheme` menu under `product`. From the dropdown, look all the way down, you'll find the menu `Edit Scheme`, select this.
  [image: Select scheme]
- Select the `Release` scheme, hit close and re-run your project in your phone.
  [image: Select release scheme]

Note: if you are building for release, make sure your target device is `Generic iOS Device`

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: the thing is there is no ios folder avaiable，really a newbie ：D

Comment: Interesting, seems you are on create-react-native-app. These steps would work with react-native-cli (react-native init ProjectName).  Haven't tried with ejected create-react-native-app though :)